# GitLab CI - Trying to use docker buildx to build for ARM64

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

Trying to use `docker buildx` with GitLabs shared runners to build a Docker image that can be run on my Raspberry Pi. Job fails saying git is not in PATH but git is installed in `image: docker:stable-git`. Any known fixes or a better way to build an ARM64-compatible image without having to build on the Raspberry Pi itself? (RPi becomes unusable while building on it due to CPU usage)

```
deploy:
  image: docker:stable-git
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    - export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
    - docker build --platform=local -o . git://github.com/docker/buildx
    - mv buildx ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  script:
    - docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
```

```
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
$ export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
$ docker build --platform=local -o . git://github.com/docker/buildx
#1 [internal] load git source git://github.com/docker/buildx
#1 ERROR: failed to init repo at /var/lib/docker/overlay2/xxx/diff: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
------
 > [internal] load git source git://github.com/docker/buildx:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to resolve dockerfile: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: failed to init repo at /var/lib/docker/overlay2/xxx/diff: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the issue was that the build was failing due to git not being installed in `docker:dind`

Was able to work around the issue by cloning [Docker/BuildX](https://github.com/docker/buildx) in a separate stage, running `docker build` on it, then exporting it to the deploy stage using artifacts.

```
buildx:
  image: docker:19.03-git
  stage: buildx
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - buildx
    expire_in: 1 hour
  services:
    - docker:19.03-dind
  script:
    - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
    - git clone git://github.com/docker/buildx ./docker-buildx
    - docker build --platform=local -o . ./docker-buildx

deploy:
  image: docker:19.03
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03-dind
      command: ["--experimental"]
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
    - mv buildx ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
    - docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker buildx create --use --name mybuilder
    - docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 --push -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
```

I've decided to update my answer with info about using BuildX in CircleCI due to changes made by GitLab to free accounts as well as comments posted by [j0nl1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9195230) and [Yajo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1468388)

You can download the BuildX binary and use it in your CircleCI job by doing the following

```
jobs:
  build-and-push:
    executor: docker/machine
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Remove old installation
          command: |
            sudo systemctl stop docker.service
            sudo apt remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
      - docker/install-docker:
          install-dir: /usr/bin
      - run:
          name: Restart docker daemon with experimental features
          command: |
            sudo bash -c 'echo "{\"experimental\":true}" > /etc/docker/daemon.json'
            if [[ $EUID == 0 ]]; then export SUDO=""; else export SUDO="sudo"; fi
            $SUDO systemctl unmask docker.service
            $SUDO systemctl unmask docker.socket
            $SUDO systemctl start docker.service
      - run:
          name: Install buildx
          command: |
            BUILDX_VERSION="v0.4.1"

            curl -sSLo docker-buildx "https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/$BUILDX_VERSION/buildx-$BUILDX_VERSION.linux-amd64"
            chmod a+x docker-buildx
            mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
            mv docker-buildx ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx

            docker version
            docker buildx install
      - docker/check:
          registry: $DOCKER_REGISTRY
      - run:
          name: Create buildx profile
          command: |
            docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
            docker buildx create --use --name mybuilder
      - docker/build:
          registry: $DOCKER_REGISTRY
          image: username/repo
          tag: latest
          extra_build_args: --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 --push
```

Comment: I'm trying to achive the same but in bitbucket the problem is I can't run dind, did you figure out another method to build multiarch images?

Comment: @j0nl1 No, this was the only method I was able to come up with. Depending on your situation you could possibly use the "CI/CD for external repo" option in GitLabs new project page. It pulls your project from git for you to run the pipeline.

Comment: I tried differents ways but I couldn't use bitbucket pipeline so I finally used circleci, I found a orb already configured and it's work like a charm.
https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/foodles/docker-buildx#jobs-publish

Comment: You don't need to build the buildx plugin because you can download it directly from Github. This way, you skip the whole `buildx` stage above: `curl -sSLo ~/.docker/cli-plugins/buildx https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/$BUILDX_VERSION/buildx-$BUILDX_VERSION.linux-amd64 && chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/buildx`

Comment: @Yajo `docker-buildx` instead of `buildx` in your script. And also `curl` doesn't work due to the encoding. This command should work: `wget -O ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/$BUILDX_VERSION/buildx-$BUILDX_VERSION.linux-amd64 && chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx`

Comment: @rpi_guru curl works perfectly fine and the file name does not matter. The edit in my answer about CircleCI works as intended and uses a method very similar to what Yajo commented.